# My processing thread is going too fast for my UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, synchronize

I have a C# program that is checking for the existence of files and registry keys and using `AppendText()` on a `Form.Textbox` for every file and registry key it is looking for.

This is running in an asynchronous `BackgroundWorker` and now my background worker is actually processing so quickly that my UI thread gets clogged up with `AppendText` commands and the program crashes.  How can I synchronize the `BackgroundWorker` and UI thread so that the `BackgroundWorker` doesn't start processing again until the UI thread is ready?

Comment: Can you show us some code? I don't see how what you've said could make sense.

Comment: Have you tried binding to the data?

Comment: Have you tried System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke method?

Comment: A WaitHandle maybe...

Comment: It also would be useful to know if you want to slow down producer thread, speed up consumer (UI) thread and what kind of data is being shown.

Comment: nice question it would be great, if you can share your code with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `BackgroundWorker`, so you have everything you need. The progress event is called on the UI thread, so if the worker reports progress in the standard way (by calling [ReportProgress(int32, object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx), and passing the string to be appended as the second parameter, the form's progress handler can call `AppendText`. The background thread will never outrun the UI that way.

I suspect you're calling `BeginInvoke` to update your UI. Another way to solve the problem would be to call `Invoke`.

You can do much better if you have your background worker save up, say, 10 lines, and then pass them all to the progress event at once. That'll reduce the overhead of updates and cause your background thread to process faster.

Answer (score 0):

One way that comes to mind is queuing the commands and allowing the UI thread to handle them at its own speed :: IE create a generic list (let's call it appendtext) of the arguments, the background worker adds to the list and the UI thread reads, calls, then deletes from the list

Comment: Or better yet; stop trying to do the updates one-at-a-time, but do them in batches.

Comment: That's a great idea...  Load what changes you want done in to a list, and the UI updates everything in the list every tick :)

Comment: Yup, exactly! Doing tiny updates is probably a big part of the problem